# problema con el catch en netbeans

Tags: netbeans, maven, apache-netbeans

[image]
Tengo una duda con este erro doy para solucionar pero no me descarga ninguna dependencia, cual seria mi error o que me faltaría es con maven de manera normal no me salta el error

este es el codigo

```
public void buscar() {
  
    
    try{
      cn.sentencia= cn.conexion.createStatement();
      cn.resultado= cn.sentencia.executeQuery("select nomousu from usuario where nomusu="+txtadmin.getText()+"' ");
      boolean encontro = cn.resultado.next();
      if(encontro==true){
          
                contra.setEnabled(true);
                contra.requestFocus();
                txtadmin.setEnabled(false);

      }else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "El usuario no Existe", "Verifique", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                txtadmin.setText(null);
                txtadmin.requestFocus();
            } catch (SQLExeption ex){
                    Logger.getLogger(acceso.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


  } 
  
  
}
```

y este es la solucion que me brinda el asistente  y al abrir ese solución me salta la posible solución en la primera imagen pero no me agrega ninguna
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Antonio. Por favor, pon el código y los mensajes de error como texto, no como imagen. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar la pregunta.

Comment: listo le agregue el codigo y la posible solucion que brinda el asistente estoy probando recien lo que es maven

Comment: Revisa tu archivo `pom.xml`, si tienes bien puesta la dependencia del controlador JDBC no deberías tener problemas con la clase `SQLException`. Agrega a la pregunta el código de la dependencia de JDBC o si quieres muéstranos tu `pom.xml` completo.

Comment: Por otra parte, parece que el `catch` está mal ubicado en tu código, tienes un `else` que es parte del bloque `try`  y el `catch` dentro de ese `else` ¿? Eso no es correcto. Tienes que cerrar el `else` y poner el `catch` por fuera. Algo así: `try {  if (...) { //... } else { //... } } catch (SQLExeption ex){ //... } }` [Revisa el tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catch.html) y escribe tus bloques como se indica allí.

Comment: Agrega -otro- `}` antes del `catch`. Indentando bien el código es más fácil notar este tipo de errores.

Answer (score 0):

Tu problema no es que te falte una dependencia, lo que está mal es el catch. Las excepciones de SQL se capturan con la clase `SQLException` y no `SQLExeption`. Cambia el `catch` de la siguiente forma:

```
...
catch (SQLException ex){
...
```

El otro problema es que tú `catch` no está alineado al `try` el catch debería ir luego del bloque `try`, es decir en la línea siguiente luego de `}` de:

```
try{
      cn.sentencia= cn.conexion.createStatement();
      cn.resultado= cn.sentencia.executeQuery("select nomousu from usuario where nomusu="+txtadmin.getText()+"' ");
      boolean encontro = cn.resultado.next();
      if(encontro==true){
          
                contra.setEnabled(true);
                contra.requestFocus();
                txtadmin.setEnabled(false);

      }else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "El usuario no Existe", "Verifique", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                txtadmin.setText(null);
                txtadmin.requestFocus();
            }
 }catch (SQLException ex){
                    
    Logger.getLogger(acceso.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```